# Why it's not adding gaps between the prefabs?

Tags: unity, c#

gap value is 7 but all the prefabs Instantiated at 0,0,0

```
private void GenerateLines()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
        {
            var prefab = Instantiate(linesPointsPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);

            prefab.transform.position = new Vector3(prefab.transform.position.x * gap, prefab.transform.position.y * gap, prefab.transform.position.z * gap);
            prefab.transform.parent = linesParent.transform;
        }
    }
```

After added gaps between the prefabs it's creating lines using linerenderer between the prefabs. then when I drag the prefabs around it's making curved lines and then the NAVI object can move on the curved lines :

[image: curved]

[image: positions]

It was working before too but I wanted to generate the curved lines automatic.
So with the gaps I can drag the prefabs around and make curved lines and next I will add automatic random positions option too so it will make the curved lines already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
var prefab = Instantiate(linesPointsPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
```

Creates an *instance* of the prefab at (0, 0, 0).

(I'd recommend calling this variable "instance" or "line" or something because it's *not* a prefab now, it's a scene object)

Then this line:

```
prefab.transform.position = new Vector3(prefab.transform.position.x * gap, prefab.transform.position.y * gap, prefab.transform.position.z * gap);
```

Multiplies the `x`, `y`, and `z` of its position by `gap`.

But `x`, `y`, and `z` are all zero, since you spawned this instance at `Vector3.zero`

```
0 * gap = 0
```

You might have wanted to combine these lines into one, something like this:

```
var instance = Instantiate(
                  linesPointsPrefab, 
                  Vector3.right * gap * i,
                  Quaternion.identity
               );
```

This says "place each new instance exactly `gap` units further to the `right` than the one before it" (change the direction if you want them stacked vertically or in the z axis, etc)

Comment: Or he meant something like prefab.transform.position.x + numberOfLines * gap since it would not much sense to spawn all of them again on top of each other .

Comment: You'll need some term in that expression that varies from one iteration of the loop to the next, @Zibelas. And I'd recommend using "they" pronouns if we don't know yet what pronouns a particular user uses.

Comment: I will try. English is not my first language and in Europe (or the part where I live) the whole pronouns and personal identification are not that critically viewed.

Comment: The reason I want to gaps is that on each prefab there is a script that use linerenderer and only when there is a gap between two prefabs it's creating a line between them and then add positions to the linerenderer in another script.  If I create the prefabs just all of them at the same place it will not add positions to the linerenderer.  Now with the gaps when there is positions in the linerenderer I can drag the prefabs around in the scene and it will make curve lines between the prefabs.